# backgroundColor and onClick Wont Take Effect React JS In Basic React App

Tags: reactjs

I am going through a React Learning Textbook that is explaining me about Hooks. The hooks part is working fine.

The author is illustrating how to customize Hooks with some easy to use style and related components.

I have the following code.

```
import React from 'react';
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import StarRating from './components/StarRating';
import StarRating2 from './components/StarRating2';
import Headline from './components/Headline';

function App() {
  return (
    <article>
      <Headline/>       
      <StarRating/>
      <StarRating2
       style={{ backgroundColor: "blue" }}
       onClick={e => alert(" click")}
      />
    </article>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The component code is like this.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";
import { FaStar } from "react-icons/fa";

const createArray = length => [...Array(length)];

const Star = ({ selected = false, onSelect = f => f }) => (
    <FaStar color={selected ? "red" : "grey"} onClick={onSelect} />
  );

const numberOfStarts = 10;
const numberDefaultState = 7;


function StarRating2({ totalStars = numberOfStarts }) 
{
    //will hold the user’s rating
    // create this variable by adding the useState hook directly to the StarRating component:
    const [selectedStars, setSelectedStars] = useState(numberDefaultState);
    return (
      <>
        <p>
          This is Star Rating 2 - and it has some imporvements
        </p>            
        {createArray(totalStars).map((n, i) => (
          <Star
            key={i}
            selected={selectedStars > i}
            onSelect=   {
            () =>   { 
                        setSelectedStars(i + 1);
                                                
                    }
                        }
          />
        ))}
        <p>
          {selectedStars} of {totalStars} stars
        </p>
      </>
    );
}

export default StarRating2;
```

Unfortunately, neither does the component display change its back ground color. Nor does it respond to a click. The app continues to run with no errors or anything. and I can see that the style properties set are visible in the component tree in the react developer tools in Firefox. So, the code is reflecting on the app for sure.

I am in the 6th chapter now, and so far, every chapter code has worked exactly as it is in the book. This one though, is not. I am unsure if this a wrong code (and perhaps, I should reach out to the author) or this is something that is no longer allowed and the book is simply out of date.

Comment: I put this code in a sandbox (minus the icon dependency); seems to be working okay. What is not happening here that you'd expect to see? https://codesandbox.io/s/background-and-onclick-d5d10

Comment: looking at both the answers below (and the textbook seems to talk about, but a few sections later) that the actual effect only happens after passing props. right now, in the codebox (I just realized, going forward, I will my code in code sandbox), I dont get the background color or the click event. but yes, once we add it props it should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StarRating2` is a React component, you are passing couple of props to `StarRating2` but you aren't using those props inside `StarRating2` component. **CSS styles and event handlers work on native DOM elements**.

What you need to do is make use of the props that are passed to `StarRating2` in from `App` component. You can apply the `styles` prop on the wrapper element that wraps all the JSX code of `StarRating2` component and use `onClick` prop on the element which should react to the click event in some way.

To apply the background color in `StarRating2` component, wrap the JSX code in a wrapper element, for example a `div` and then use the value of `style` prop on this wrapper element.

```
function StarRating2({ totalStars = numberOfStarts, style }) {
  ...

  return (
    <div style={style}>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

To use the click handler, you will need to use the `onClick` prop and add it on any native DOM element.

Comment: I keep forgetting that part about native DOM elements. Right, yes. still need to get into the React way of thinking along with JS way of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

You need to spread the props from the parent to a native react component , styles and eventListeners can only be attached to native components like div , button etc , if the Star component supports adding color and eventListeners through its , you can do ... rest in props and spread it to star component , if you need any help , send me a codesandbox , I will explain in that